In EXCEL, get ALL named ranges, and set them as variables
In my Excel VBA, I have well over 100 lines of code similar to the following.
Is there a way to loop through all existing named ranges, and set a variable with a name equal to the name of the named range, and with the value of the named range?
Public Development, include_nfm, include_dod, email_cc

    With Worksheets("CS_INPUTS")
        Development = .Range("Development").Value
        include_nfm = .Range("include_nfm").Value
        include_dod = .Range("include_dod").Value
        email = .Range("email").Value
    End With


No, you can't create variables dynamically. An alternative might be a Scripting.Dictionary. This sounds like an XY problem though. What's the end goal?

This may be of use

@BigBen As an OT technically you can if you use .CodeModule.Insertlines. However, I agree that a dictionary or an array is the actual tool needed here. Probably a mix where you loop through the defined array elements to create a dictionary

Can you tell us what you intend to use the variables for? As they're all individually named it would seem that its just for human readability. Is that the case?

@ryan What is your end goal? Why would you declare something if you do not know what you'll use that variable for? Plus you are not accounting if that will be a string, a long, a boolean, etc.

@CLR The variables are largely strings that are used to replace text in various documents to build a report.
Generalized example: The [COLOR] Fox jumped over the lazy [ANIMAL].
Where [COLOR] is replaced by a variable "color" that is equal to brown, and [ANIMAL] gets replaced by a variable "animal" that is equal to "dog".
The result would be: The brown Fox jumped over the lazy dog.

If that is your goal, perhaps this may give you a framework to start? In addition, I think that the dictionary is the solution to go for if its for another case than word where you can loop through its elements easier

Added comment, most of the documents are simple text documents, not Word. Also the named fields in the Excel Spreadsheet are all over the place, not in neat predictable columns.

If you need some intermediate step between named ranges and documents, a Scripting.Dictionary is a great candidate.

Here's something to get you going:
Sub try_this()

    Dim dict As Object, k As Variant
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = TextCompare
    
    'Read the named ranges into the dictionary
    For Each nm In Names
        If nm.RefersToRange.Parent.Name = "CS_INPUTS" Then
            'Debug.Print nm.Name, nm.RefersTo, nm.RefersToRange.Value
            dict.Add nm.Name, nm.RefersToRange.Value
        End If
    Next
    
    'Output the dictionary
    For Each k In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print k, dict(k)
    Next
    
End Sub


Answer:
Per your comments since the ultimate goal is to replace the values of named ranges in a txt file, this would be the approach for it
Sub Exec_ReplaceNamingVariables()
Dim TxtFilePath As String
Dim ItemName As Name
Dim RangeItemName As Range
Dim DictToReplace As Object: Set DictToReplace = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    'Begin: not needed just to show the before
    TxtFilePath = "C:/Test.txt"
    Shell "notepad.exe " & TxtFilePath, vbNormalFocus
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    AppActivate "Notepad"
    SendKeys "%{F4}"
    'End: not needed just to show the before
    For Each ItemName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    Set RangeItemName = ItemName.RefersToRange
    DictToReplace.Add CStr(ItemName.Name), CStr(Format(RangeItemName.Value, RangeItemName.NumberFormat))
    Next ItemName
    Call Exec_ReplaceInTextFile(TxtFilePath, DictToReplace)
    Set DictToReplace = Nothing
    'not needed just to show the after
    Shell "notepad.exe " & TxtFilePath, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
Sub Exec_ReplaceInTextFile(TxtFilePath As String, DictToReplace As Object)
Dim TxtFileContent As String
Dim ItemKey As Variant
    Open TxtFilePath For Input As #1
    TxtFileContent = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1
    For Each ItemKey In DictToReplace.Keys
    TxtFileContent = Replace(TxtFileContent, ItemKey, DictToReplace(ItemKey), Compare:=vbBinaryCompare)
    Next ItemKey
    Open TxtFilePath For Output As #1
    Print #1, TxtFileContent
    Close #1
End Sub

Demo:

Limitations:
Since replace does not have a way to compare either full or partial text (that I have found about) you need to be careful with names declarations in excel as this may overlap and as shown in the demo surname gets replaced by name. That is something you need to think in how to do workarounds
